# Upperbound for $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i^2}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

Suppose that $x_i>0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. I'm looking for an upperbound (doesn't have to be particularly tight) of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i^2}$ in terms of some symmetric function of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, preferably $\sum\limits_{i}x_i$.

Using Jensen's inequality and the convexity of $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x^2}$, I can see that
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i}\frac{1}{x_i^2}\geq\frac{1}{\left(\sum\limits_i\frac{x_i}{n}\right)^2}\implies\sum\limits_{i}\frac{1}{x_i^2}\geq\frac{n^3}{(\sum_ix_i)^2},
$$
but of course the inequality here goes in the undesirable direction.

Thank you.

**Edit**: In the context I'm considering, the $x_i$'s are eigenvalues.

Comment: As a first comment, using the inequalities for $\ell_p$ norms you have a bound of $\left(\sum_i \frac{1}{x_i}\right)^2$. Would that be good enough?

Comment: @ClementC. Oh thanks. Let me think in that direction a bit.

Comment: How about $\sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{1}{x_i^2}\leq \frac{n}{\big(\min\left\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right\}\big)^2}$?  The upper bound I give is definitely a symmetric function in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$.  For your information, any function of $\sum_{i=1}^n\,x_i$ may not be an upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{1}{x_i^2}$ (i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^n\,\frac{1}{x_i^2}$ can be as large as we want, regardless of $\sum_{i=1}^n\,x_i$).

Comment: @Batominovski You're right. Your last comment saves me a lot of time.